# Understand bootstrap 'clearfix'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, clearfix

I do not understand how to use `clearfix`. I have [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/aOemyfFVJt) as an example. There's a Bootstrap carousel and, next section, is not appearing right below it. I assume this is `floating` problem but I don't know how to solve it.

Can anyone explain it how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: carousel works like this.the sections are shown side by side . So what is the problem?

Comment: I want the section with red background to show right below the carousel, without the white space. I know how to achieve that, but I thought it was a floating problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS you have `.carousel { margin-bottom: 60px; }`. Remove it.